# Logging in with un registered email address throws exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm having a little logic problem logging into the site. If there is no registered email address I want validation on the page to fail and show a message under the email address field that says something like "Email address doesn't exist" or something to that nature.

But I'm not sure how this code below for login should take care of that...

In this code below 'user' is null when no email address is found so PasswordSignInAsync throws an exception because the user.UserName property is null.

How would I handle the validation for this and shouldn't this be already built into the logic for the ASP.Net MVC template with single sign on I created?

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
            {
                string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account-Resend");

                // Uncomment to debug locally  
                // ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
                ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on. "
                                     + "The confirmation token has been resent to your email account.";
                return View("Error");
            }
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the message "Invalid login attempt" is shown as validation error for the e-mail address field, you have to set the ModelError for the specific property of your viewModel which is holding the e-mail address.

So it should look like this, whereas the "EmailAdress" is the name of the viewModel property:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("EmailAddress", "Invalid login attempt.");
```